# Qual a origem da palavra boche?

Tags: etimologia

Boche é um termo depreciativo usado costumeiramente como referência a uma pessoa (frequentemente um homem) de origem alemã.

Será que este termo teve a sua origem com o nome alemão Bosch, ou teve uma origem diferente?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A origem é francesa. https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/boche

[At wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_terms_used_for_Germans#Boches_.28offensive.2C_historical.29)

> #### Boches (offensive, historical)
>
> Apheresis of the word **alboche**, which in turn is a blend of
> **allemand** (French for German) and **caboche** (slang for head). Used mainly during the First and Second World Wars, and directed
> especially at German soldiers.

Note: Apheresis - loss of sound at the beginning of a word.

Comment: I really do not like people editing my answers. If I choose to put square brackets in my text, kindly leave it be. Now, Jorge B. you have removed the clickable LINK to the wikepedia ENTRY which has many other INTERESTING things in it. Eu tinha recolocado a resposta do meu modo, e mas uma vez, alguem mexeu no formato. I give up.